# Confirm simulation results algebraically for this function

Tags: probability, proof-writing

I have data for a variable $x$, denoted $x_1$ to $x_n$.

I have the following function:

$$ \lambda(x) = \frac{\sum_i x_i \left(x_i^{\frac{\phi}{1-\phi}} - c\right)^{-\frac{1}{\phi}}}{\sum_i x_i^{\frac{1}{1-\phi}} \left(x_i^{\frac{\phi}{1-\phi}} - c\right)^{-\frac{1}{\phi}}} $$

where $c \in (0,1)$ and $\phi \in (-\infty,1)$.

I want to understand how a **mean-preserving change in $x$ affects $\lambda(x)$.** For this, I create a new variable $y$, from $y_1$ to $y_n$, such that

$$ y_i = x_i + \epsilon_i $$

where $\epsilon$ is white noise, independent from $x$. This means that $E(y)=E(x)$ and $V(y)>V(x)$. **In other words, $y$ has the same mean than $x$, but higher variance.**

Then, I can also define

$$ \lambda(y) = \frac{\sum_i y_i \left(y_i^{\frac{\phi}{1-\phi}} - c\right)^{-\frac{1}{\phi}}}{\sum_i y_i^{\frac{1}{1-\phi}} \left(y_i^{\frac{\phi}{1-\phi}} - c\right)^{-\frac{1}{\phi}}} $$

As said, **I am interesting in characterising the relationship between $\lambda(y)$ and $\lambda(x)$.** Simulations tell me that

$$ \lambda(y) > \lambda(x) \quad \text{if} \quad 0 < \phi < 1 $$

$$ \lambda(y) = \lambda(x) \quad \text{if} \quad \phi = 0 $$

$$ \lambda(y) < \lambda(x) \quad \text{if} \quad \phi < 0 $$

This is, the correlation between $\lambda(z)$ and $V(z)$ can be positive, zero, or negative, depending on the value of $\phi$ (think of a graph with $\sigma^2_{\epsilon}$ in the horizontal axis, and $\lambda$ in the vertical one. The slope depends on $\phi$).

**I want to "confirm" these results algebraically.** Yet, I am stuck. I think I need to do this in terms of random variables, and not in terms of data. Thus, I have changed the notation as follows (replacing sample average with expected value, dividing by N and taking limit):

$$ \lambda(x) = \frac{E\left[x_i f(x_i)\right]}{E\left[x_i^{\frac{1}{1-\phi}} f(x_i)\right]} $$

$$ \lambda(y) = \frac{E\left[y_i f(y_i)\right]}{E\left[y_i^{\frac{1}{1-\phi}} f(y_i)\right]} $$

where $f(x_i) = \left(x_i^{\frac{\phi}{1-\phi}} - c\right)^{-\frac{1}{\phi}} $, and similar for $f(y_i)$.

I can go one step further by replacing $E\left[x_i f(x_i)\right]$ with $E(x_i)E(f(x_i)) + cov(x_i,f(x_i))$ and etc. But I see no way to proceed, other that using $E(y)=E(x)$ and replacing $y_i = x_i + \epsilon_i $ in the covariance. I am basically stuck at:

$$ \lambda(x) = \frac{E(x_i)E(f(x_i)) + cov(x_i,f(x_i))}{E(x_i^{\frac{1}{1-\phi}})E(f(x_i)) + cov(x_i^{\frac{1}{1-\phi}},f(x_i))} $$

$$ \lambda(y) = \frac{E(x_i)E(f(y_i)) + cov(x_i,f(y_i)) + cov(\epsilon_i,f(y_i))}{E(y_i^{\frac{1}{1-\phi}})E(f(y_i)) + cov(y_i^{\frac{1}{1-\phi}},f(y_i))} $$

Is there some property or mathematical toolbox that might help move further? Perhaps some type of inequality in terms of expectation? I am not sure a Taylor approximation would help, because simulations show this is a general result (neither relative to a fixed point nor an approximation). Any idea?

PS: I am not asking you to solve this problem for me, but to get some hints on how to move forward. My toolbox is quite limited and just don't know how to proceed.